# Skipping blank cells when using concatenate in a list's calculated column

Tags: list, column, calculated-column

I am using Concatenate in a calculated column to combine information from two columns in a list like this =CONCATENATE(A2, ", ",B2," feet").  Can you help me with a formula that would leave the field blank when the respective cell for column A is blank instead of returning ", feet"? Column B would always be empty if column A is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a conditional check for column A to be blank.

```
=IF(A<>"",CONCATENATE(A,", ",B, " feet"),"")
```

If A isn't blank, it'll return the concatenation, otherwise it returns an empty string.

Comment: There it is!  That did the trick.  Thanks very much.

Comment: if it solve your problem, please mark it as close for community benefits.